# Using Python to add a list of files into a zip file

Tags: python, zip

I want to write a script to add all the ‘.py’ files into a zip file.

Here is what I have:

```
import zipfile
import os

working_folder = 'C:\\Python27\\'

files = os.listdir(working_folder)

files_py = []

for f in files:
    if f[-2:] == 'py':
        fff = working_folder + f
        files_py.append(fff)

ZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile("zip testing.zip", "w" )

for a in files_py:
    ZipFile.write(a, zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

However it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\working.py", line 19, in <module>
    ZipFile.write(str(a), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1121, in write
    arcname = os.path.normpath(os.path.splitdrive(arcname)[1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 125, in splitdrive
    if p[1:2] == ':':
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

so seems the file names given is not correct.

Comment: what line? show the full trace

Comment: ah, Mr. Pieters, how are you? it's the actual name. I tried to change it to 'testing.zip', neither working.

Comment: @MarkK: Yeah, I already discounted that in the meantime, sorry for asking about that without verifying what `arcname` is in the source. I located the problem already, see my answer.

Comment: thanks, Mr. Pieters. it works, and adds the whole folder contains the wanted files into the zip file. is there a way just add them all, instead into a folder before adding?

Comment: Just a quick note, use os.path.join(working_folder, f) to generate the real path, don't use string concatenation directly '+'

Comment: @e-nouri, thanks for the note. could you please tell me why it is important?

Comment: @MarkK: with `os.path()` your code can be made cross-platform more easily, as the library takes care of the correct path separators. You also don't need to care as much about providing a path separator at the end of `working_folder`.

Comment: @MarkK: on the same note, you can use `str.endswith()` instead of slicing: `if f.endswith('.py'):`.

Comment: @MarkK: and `ZipFile` doesn't require anything to be collected into one folder. You can give it any list of files, then provide the second `arcname` argument to specify the filename (with path) within the archive. `os.path.basename()` could work for example to put all files in a flat hierarchy.

Comment: @MarkK As the Master Martin said :D your code will be cross plateform and it won't break of you run on windows or linux, also it is better than dealing with string directly, because you don't have to add additional checks. Check the documentation for the os.path function you will find some great information there, Cheers !

Comment: thanks, Mr. Pieters and e-nouri!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to pass in the compression type as a keyword argument:

```
ZipFile.write(a, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Without the keyword argument, you are giving `ZipFile.write()` an integer `arcname` argument instead, and that is causing the error you see as the `arcname` is being normalised.

Answer (score 7):

***original answered Sep 2 '14 at 3:52***

according to the guidance above, the final is:
(just putting them together in case it could be useful)

```
import zipfile
import os

working_folder = 'C:\\Python27\\'

files = os.listdir(working_folder)

files_py = []

for f in files:
    if f.endswith('py'):
        fff = os.path.join(working_folder, f)
        files_py.append(fff)

ZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile("zip testing3.zip", "w" )

for a in files_py:
    ZipFile.write(os.path.basename(a), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
ZipFile.close()
```

**added in Mar 2020**
enlightened by @jinzy at [zip file and avoid directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991745/zip-file-and-avoid-directory-structure), the last line of above changed to below to avoid file structures in the zip file.

```
ZipFile.write(a, "C:\\" + os.path.basename(a), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: after the for loop, you should close the ZipFile using ZipFile.close()