# zip file and avoid directory structure

Tags: python, zip

I have a Python script that zips a file (`new.txt`):

```
tofile =  "/root/files/result/"+file
targetzipfile = new.zip # This is how I want my zip to look like
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(targetzipfile, mode='w')
try:
    #adding to archive
    zf.write(tofile)
finally:
    zf.close()
```

When I do this I get the zip file.  But when I try to unzip the file I get the text file inside of a series of directories corresponding to the path of the file i.e I see a folder called `root` in the `result` directory and more directories within it, i.e. I have

```
/root/files/result/new.zip
```

and when I unzip `new.zip` I have a directory structure that looks like

```
/root/files/result/root/files/result/new.txt
```

Is there a way I can zip such that when I unzip I only get `new.txt`?

In other words I have `/root/files/result/new.zip` and when I unzip `new.zip`, it should look like

```
/root/files/results/new.txt
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The `zipfile.write()` method takes an optional `arcname` argument that specifies what the name of the file should be inside the zipfile

I think you need to do a modification for the destination, otherwise it will duplicate the directory. Use :`arcname` to avoid it. try like this:

```
import os
import zipfile

def zip(src, dst):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile("%s.zip" % (dst), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for filename in files:
            absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
            print 'zipping %s as %s' % (os.path.join(dirname, filename),
                                        arcname)
            zf.write(absname, arcname)
    zf.close()

zip("src", "dst")
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to specify arcname to avoid it walking through all parent folders up to root, if i'm giving a file path why won't it just consider just the file?

Comment: you can change arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:] for arcname = os.path.basename(absname)

Answer (score 22):

```
zf.write(tofile)
```

to change

```
zf.write(tofile, zipfile_dir)
```

for example

```
zf.write("/root/files/result/root/files/result/new.txt", "/root/files/results/new.txt")
```

Comment: @user34551743, superb!

Answer (score 14):

To illustrate most clearly,

directory structure:

```
/Users
 └── /user
 .    ├── /pixmaps
 .    │    ├── pixmap_00.raw
 .    │    ├── pixmap_01.raw
      │    ├── /jpeg
      │    │    ├── pixmap_00.jpg
      │    │    └── pixmap_01.jpg
      │    └── /png
      │         ├── pixmap_00.png
      │         └── pixmap_01.png
      ├── /docs
      ├── /programs
      ├── /misc
      .
      .
      .
```

Directory of interest: ***/Users/user/pixmaps***

**First attemp**

```
import os
import zipfile

TARGET_DIRECTORY = "/Users/user/pixmaps"
ZIPFILE_NAME = "CompressedDir.zip"

def zip_dir(directory, zipname):
    """
    Compress a directory (ZIP file).
    """
    if os.path.exists(directory):
        outZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in filenames:

                filepath   = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                outZipFile.write(filepath)

        outZipFile.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    zip_dir(TARGET_DIRECTORY, ZIPFILE_NAME)
```

ZIP file structure:

```
CompressedDir.zip
.
└── /Users
     └── /user
          └── /pixmaps
               ├── pixmap_00.raw
               ├── pixmap_01.raw
               ├── /jpeg
               │    ├── pixmap_00.jpg
               │    └── pixmap_01.jpg
               └── /png
                    ├── pixmap_00.png
                    └── pixmap_01.png
```

**Avoiding the full directory path**

```
def zip_dir(directory, zipname):
    """
    Compress a directory (ZIP file).
    """
    if os.path.exists(directory):
        outZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        # The root directory within the ZIP file.
        rootdir = os.path.basename(directory)

        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in filenames:

                # Write the file named filename to the archive,
                # giving it the archive name 'arcname'.
                filepath   = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                parentpath = os.path.relpath(filepath, directory)
                arcname    = os.path.join(rootdir, parentpath)

                outZipFile.write(filepath, arcname)

    outZipFile.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    zip_dir(TARGET_DIRECTORY, ZIPFILE_NAME)
```

ZIP file structure:

```
CompressedDir.zip
.
└── /pixmaps
     ├── pixmap_00.raw
     ├── pixmap_01.raw
     ├── /jpeg
     │    ├── pixmap_00.jpg
     │    └── pixmap_01.jpg
     └── /png
          ├── pixmap_00.png
          └── pixmap_01.png
```

Comment: In the second program, I think the line `outZipFile.close()` should be *inside* the `if` block.

Answer (score 11):

The `arcname` parameter in the write method specifies what will be the name of the file inside the zipfile:

```
import os
import zipfile

# 1. Create a zip file which we will write files to
zip_file = "/home/username/test.zip"
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

# 2. Write files found in "/home/username/files/" to the test.zip
files_to_zip = "/home/username/files/"
for file_to_zip in os.listdir(files_to_zip):

    file_to_zip_full_path = os.path.join(files_to_zip, file_to_zip)

    # arcname argument specifies what will be the name of the file inside the zipfile
    zipf.write(filename=file_to_zip_full_path, arcname=file_to_zip)

zipf.close()
```

Comment: Out of every answer, yours was the simplest and quickly made me understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can isolate just the file name of your sources files using:

```
name_file_only= name_full_path.split(os.sep)[-1]
```

For example, if `name_full_path` is `/root/files/results/myfile.txt`, then `name_file_only` will be `myfile.txt`. To zip myfile.txt to the root of the archive `zf`, you can then use:

```
zf.write(name_full_path, name_file_only)
```

Comment: If you had a different question which does not exist, then I think you should ask that question, and then answer your own question. You will help others (maybe even yourself in the future) when they search with a more relevant question.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the documentation for **Zipfile.write**.

> ZipFile.write(filename[, arcname[, compress_type]]) Write the file
>   named filename to the archive, giving it the archive name arcname (by
>   default, this will be the same as filename, but without a drive letter
>   and with leading path separators removed)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

Try the following:

```
import zipfile
import os
filename = 'foo.txt'

# Using os.path.join is better than using '/' it is OS agnostic
path = os.path.join(os.path.sep, 'tmp', 'bar', 'baz', filename)
zip_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.zip'
zip_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), zip_filename)

# If you need exception handling wrap this in a try/except block
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w') as zf:
    zf.write(path, zip_filename)
```

The bottom line is that if you do not supply an archive name then the filename is used as the archive name and it will contain the full path to the file.

Answer (score 5):

It is much simpler than expected, I configured the module using the parameter "arcname" as "file_to_be_zipped.txt", so the folders do not appear in my final zipped file:

```
mmpk_zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile("c:\\Destination_folder_name\newzippedfilename.zip", mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
mmpk_zip_file.write("c:\\Source_folder_name\file_to_be_zipped.txt", "file_to_be_zipped.txt")
mmpk_zip_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use this

```
import os
# single File
os.system(f"cd {destinationFolder} && zip fname.zip fname") 
# directory
os.system(f"cd {destinationFolder} && zip -r folder.zip folder")
```

For me, This is working.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the arcname input of the write method as following:

```
tofile =  "/root/files/result/"+file
NewRoot = "files/result/"
zf.write(tofile, arcname=tofile.split(NewRoot)[1])
```

More info:

> ZipFile.write(filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None,
> compresslevel=None)
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem and i solve it with `writestr`. You can use it like this:

`zipObject.writestr(<filename> , <file data, bytes or string>)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an elegant way to do it with `pathlib` you can use it this way:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import zipfile

def zip_dir(path_to_zip: Path):
    zip_file = Path(path_to_zip).with_suffix('.zip')
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for f in list(path_to_zip.rglob('*.*')):
        z.write(f, arcname=f.relative_to(path_to_zip))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the absolute path, I came up with this:

```py
def create_zip(root_path, file_name, ignored=[], storage_path=None):
    """Create a ZIP
    
    This function creates a ZIP file of the provided root path.
    
    Args:
        root_path (str): Root path to start from when picking files and directories.
        file_name (str): File name to save the created ZIP file as.
        ignored (list): A list of files and/or directories that you want to ignore. This
                        selection is applied in root directory only.
        storage_path: If provided, ZIP file will be placed in this location. If None, the
                        ZIP will be created in root_path
    """
    if storage_path is not None:
        zip_root = os.path.join(storage_path, file_name)
    else:
        zip_root = os.path.join(root_path, file_name)
        
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_root, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    def iter_subtree(path, layer=0):
        # iter the directory
        path = Path(path)
        for p in path.iterdir():
            if layer == 0 and p.name in ignored:
                continue
            zipf.write(p, str(p).replace(root_path, '').lstrip('/'))
            
            if p.is_dir():
                iter_subtree(p, layer=layer+1)

    iter_subtree(root_path)
    zipf.close()
```

Maybe it isn't the most elegant solution, but this works. If we just use `p.name` when providing the file name to `write()` method, then it doesn't create the proper directory structure.

Moreover, if it's needed to ignore the selected directories or files from the root path, this ignores those selections too.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I used. I have one excel file, Treport where I am using python + pandas in my dowork function to create pivot tables, etc. for each of the companies in CompanyNames. I create a zip file of the csv and a non-zip file so I can check as well.
The writer specifies the path where I want my .xlsx to go and for my zip files, I specify that in the zip.write(). I just specify the name of the xlsx file that was recently created, and that is what gets zipped up, not the whole directory. Beforehand I was just specifying 'writer' and would zip up the whole directory. This allows me to zip up just the recently created excel file.

```
Treport = 'TestReportData.csv'
CompanyNames = ['Company1','Company2','Company3']
for CompName in CompanyNames:
    strcomp = str(CompName)
    #Writer Creates pathway to output report to. Each company gets unique file.
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\{strcomp}addReview.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    DoWorkFunction(CompName, Treport, writer)
    writer.save()
    with ZipFile(f"C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\{strcomp}addR.zip", 'w') as zip:
        zip.write(writer, f"{strcomp}addReview.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os

filepath = "/root/files/result/new.txt"
zip_location = "/root/files/result/"
with ZipFile(zip_location, "w") as zipObj:
    zipObj.write(filepath, os.path.basename(filepath))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).