# Python - how to zip several folders from a path to a single zip file?

Tags: python-2.7, directory, zip

I have a ROOT_FOLDER_PATH with subfolders A, B, C, D, E,(...) and I want to zip folder A, C and D to a zip file EXCLUDING all the others and the ROOT_FOLDER_PATH itself with Python 2.7. How do i do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm new to SO or programming and I've started to learn python by myself about 3 weeks ago and I'm not aware of this (great!) site ethics. But I've found a solution based on another code to do exactly what I want. First I just got something that zips everything (previously removing what I don't want). Then I've startet "playing" with logic and the "if", "and", "or", "not", "in" and I've reached to this. I would like NOT to be excuded. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This goes even further than the original question. 
Provides the option to select, from root folder, the directories to zip and the option to exclude sub directories and files inside each directory selected.

```
import os
import zipfile

def zipSelectExclude(src, dst, incluDIR1, incluDIR2, incluDIR3, excluSUBDIR1a, excluSUBDIR1b, excluSUBDIR3a, excluFILE3):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile("%s.zip" % (dst), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for filename in files:
            absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
            print 'zipping %s as %s' % (os.path.join(dirname, filename),
                                        arcname)
            if incluDIR1 in dirname and excluSUBDIR1a not in dirname and excluSUBDIR1b not in dirname or incluDIR2 in dirname or incluDIR3 in dirname and excluSUBDIR3a not in dirname and excluFILE3 not in filename:
            zf.write(absname, arcname), 
    zf.close()

    """ Got the above from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991745/python-zip-file-and-avoid-directory-structure  (answer from user 12321)
    and added the 'if' statement (and the 'def' modifications) to include selected folders from root folder to zip and exclude subdirs and files.
    Be careful with the 'if' statement hierarchical order - for each folder inclusion 'in dirname' specify it's subdirectories and file exclusion
    with 'and ... not in dirname' nx"""

def zipSE():
    src = os.path.join('/PATH/TO/MY', 'rootFOLDER')
    dst = os.path.join('/PATH/TO/SAVE/MY', 'ZIPfile')
    incluDIR1 = os.path.join(src, 'incluDIR1')
    incluDIR2 = os.path.join(src, 'incluDIR2')
    incluDIR3 = os.path.join(src, 'incluDIR3')
    excluSUBDIR1a = os.path.join(incluDIR1, 'excluSUBDIR1a')
    excluSUBDIR1b = os.path.join(incluDIR1, 'excluSUBDIR1b')
    excluSUBDIR3a = os.path.join(incluDIR3, 'excluSUBDIR3a')

    zipSelectExclude(src, dst, incluDIR1, incluDIR2, incluDIR3, excluSUBDIR1a, excluSUBDIR1b, excluSUBDIR3a, 'excluFILE3')

zipSE()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the direct answer to the original Question:

```
import os
import zipfile

def zipONLY(src, dst, incluDIR1, incluDIR2, incluDIR3):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile("%s.zip" % (dst), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for filename in files:
            absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
            print 'zipping %s as %s' % (os.path.join(dirname, filename),
                                        arcname)
            """ Change the arguments and the 'if' statement to fit your needs"""
            if incluDIR1 in dirname or incluDIR2 in dirname or incluDIR3 in dirname:

            zf.write(absname, arcname),
    zf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is the oposite: zip all except...

```
import os
import zipfile

def zipALLexcept(src, dst, excluDIR1, excluDIR2, excluDIR3):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile("%s.zip" % (dst), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for filename in files:
            absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
            print 'zipping %s as %s' % (os.path.join(dirname, filename),
                                        arcname)

            """ Change the arguments and the 'if' statement to fit your needs."""
            if excluDIR1 not in dirname and excluDIR2 not in dirname and excluDIR3 not in dirname:

            zf.write(absname, arcname), 
    zf.close()
```