# How can I not include the whole path while zipping with 7zip in Python?

Tags: python, file, scripting, 7zip, data-extraction

I have a C:/a/b/c/d and I want to zip the file 'd' only. When I do it in Python using py7zr library with

```
archive = py7zr.SevenZipFile('C:/a/b/c/d.7z', 'w')
archive.writeall('C:/a/b/c/d')
archive.close()
```

it works but when i extract the zip, i end up having the whole a/b/c path, instead i want only to zip the current file. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991745/zip-file-and-avoid-directory-structure

Comment: It didn't help. I ended up using zipfile library, and it is all good

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with

```
archive = py7zr.SevenZipFile('C:/a/b/c/d.7z', 'w')
archive.writeall('C:/a/b/c/d', 'd')
archive.close()
```

Then file 'a/b/c/d/a.txt' will be archived as 'd/a.txt' instead of 'a/b/c/d/a.txt'