# Zip file and save to specific folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

this might be a silly question but I'm struggling a lot finding solution to it.

So I have a file in the given folder:

```
Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100.csv
```

Now I want to zip the file and save it to same location. So here's my try:

```
zipfile.ZipFile('Output/20190101_0100/20190101_0100_11.zip', mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED).write('Output/20190101_0100/20190101_0100_11.csv')
```

But it's making a folder insider zip folder and saving it, as shown below:

```
Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100_11.zip\Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100_11.csv
```

Can someone tell me how can I save my file directly in the same location or location mentioned below:

```
Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100_11.zip\20190101_0100_11.csv
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991745/zip-file-and-avoid-directory-structure/27992144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Rephrasing of question

The question is slightly confusing because `Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100_11.zip\Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100_11.csv` won't be a file, but rather `Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100_11.csv` will be a file within the zip file `Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100_11.zip` (if I am not mistaken)

Just to restate your problem (if I understood it correctly):

- You have a file `Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100.csv` (a file `20190101_0100.csv` in the `Output` -> `20190101_0100` sub directory)
- You want to create the zip file `Output/20190101_0100/20190101_0100_11.zip` (`20190101_0100_11.zip` in the `Output` -> `20190101_0100.zip` directory)
- You want to add the aforementioned CSV file `Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100.csv` but without the leading path, i.e. as `20190101_0100_11.csv` rather than `Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100.csv`.

Or to not get confused with too many similar directories, let's simplify it as:

- You have a file `test.csv` in the sub directory `sub-folder`
- You want to create the zip file `test.zip`
- You want to add the aforementioned CSV file `test.csv` but without the leading path, i.e. as `test.csv` rather than `sub-folder/test.csv`.

### Answer

From the [ZipFile.write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) documentation:

> Write the file named *filename* to the archive, giving it the archive
> name *arcname* (by default, this will be the same as *filename*, but
> without a drive letter and with leading path separators removed).

That means that `arcname` will default to the passed in `filename` (it doesn't have a drive letter or leading path separator).

If you want to remove the sub folder part, just pass in `arcname` as well. e.g.:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('path-to-zip/test.zip', 'w') as zf:
    zf.write('sub-folder/test.csv', arcname='test.csv')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I try the above code with my problem it's giving following error, here ```with zipfile.ZipFile('20190101_0100_11.zip') as zf```.


```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20190101_0100_11.zip'
```

Comment: Apologies, it was missing the missing mode `w` when calling `ZipFile`. I've updated the example in my answer.

Comment: my bad, I should have get that. But when I'm writing ```zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')``` it's making file in the main folder(where my python file is or outside Output file) itself. but when I added subfolder path while writing it worked.
```zipfile.ZipFile('subfolder/test.zip', 'w')```

Comment: can you change that part, so I can accept your answer sir!

Comment: I added `path-to-zip` to the example. (I had omitted it to keep it slightly more simple)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a raw path:

```
zipfile.ZipFile('Output/20190101_0100/20190101_0100_11.zip', mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED).write(r'C:\...\Output\20190101_0100\20190101_0100_11.csv')
```

Comment: thank you for an answer, but it's still doing the same thing, Inside zip folder its creating subfolder starting from C drive to destination again, and I directly want my csv file inside zip folder.