# zip a list of files and attach in email - python

Tags: python, email

I have a list of files that contain all the files that need to be zipped together for the email attachment.

Currently the code I am using is

```
if zip_file == True:
    for file in file_list:
        zf = tempfile.TemporaryFile(prefix='mail', suffix='.zip')
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zf, 'a')
        zip.write(file)
        zip.close()
        zf.seek(0)
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')
        part.set_payload(zf.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='xls_attachments' + '.zip')
        msg.attach(part)
```

This lets me create a zip file for all the files and attaches them in the mail. So If I have 10 files in `file_list` then the mail would have 10 zipped attachments. But what I want is all the 10 files into a single zip file.

I have seen examples here that say to use multiple `zip.write()` methods to write each file. But that would not be good because I cannot control the the number of entries in `file_list`.

Comment: Look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544475/using-python-to-add-a-list-of-files-into-a-zip-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compress all the files in a folder into a single zip using something like this:

```
import os
import zipfile

working_folder = 'C:\\path_to_some_folder\\'
files = os.listdir(working_folder)
files_py = files

ZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile("zip testing3.zip", "a" )

for a in files_py:
    ZipFile.write(os.path.basename(a), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
ZipFile.close()
```